# Let $A$ be the matrix below and define a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ by $T(U) = AU$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the matrix below and define a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ by $T(U) = AU$. For each of the vectors $B$ below, find a vector $U$ such that $T$ maps $U$ to $B$, if possible. Otherwise state that there is no such $U$

$A = \pmatrix{5&10&10\\2&7&10\\-1&0&2}$

1. $b = \pmatrix{0\\3\\2}$
2. $b = \pmatrix{-1\\2\\3}$.

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgFUu.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you find this question? What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show your way of thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like that:

First we define the variable $\mathrm x=\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, we want to solve the equation $A\mathrm x=b$.

That's a linear system of equation, which can be solved using gaussian elimination.

For example, if $b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\3\\2\end{bmatrix}$, the system is

$\begin{matrix}5x+10y+10z=0\\2x+7y+10z=3\\-x+2z=2\end{matrix}$

and after elimination you will get (using wolfram alpha)

$\begin{matrix}x-2z=-2\\y+2z=1\end{matrix}$

Here z is a free variable, and the solution is $\mathrm x=\begin{bmatrix}2t-2\\1-2t\\t\end{bmatrix}$.

If you choose $t=0$, you get $\mathrm x=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to give you the answer but your general strategy to solving this is to create a "generic" vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ and see where your transformation $T$ sends it: this will give you some vector $\begin{bmatrix} ac_1\\ bc_2\\ cc_3\end{bmatrix}$. Then set this equal to your target $B$ vector and see what values work! (system of equations).